# Gmail Notes - iPhone

Tags: gmail, iphone

My friend saved some text into Gmail notes IMAP folder via iPhone.

However, now when looking at them via the online gmail.com interface, they appear to be gibberish.

Example (altered for privacy):

> Okqqaahskklaapalk-2@3-22:45111040-'shake,:)8$-//$:!@:):$:444$4+{<]-*|_$]]~}&&

It looks like an encryption/encoding of a sort, but doesn't seem to match anything I'm familiar with. It's clearly neither base64 or base32, or even base85.

As far as I know, no encryption was on on the iPhone's end. This hasn't happened to all messages, only seemed to start in the last few days. Is this just corruption or what?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like extra data applied on from the client you used from your iPhone, ie, time, as shown by 22:45, unless that was part of your original message, but never the less, iOS formats things differently, and could be a Unicode parse issue, never the less, try evernote :)

Comment: That's an interesting issue. Did you copy the text from somewhere else?